Nested set function in useEffect called three times in strict mode
I got a strange behaviour in my react code:
Edit: It turns out the clear function was working and successfully cleared the interval. Now I faced another issue from strict mode double invocation. I have attached the full app code below, the set function setRow() inside another set function setSecondPassed() has been called 3 times per interval, and one of the time the value has updated another time. I assume under double invocation and if my code is well written, they should be idempotent but inside each interval the state of rows updated twice.
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Timer />
    </>
  );
}
function Timer() {
  const [secondsPassed, setSecondPassed] = useState(0);
  const [rows, setRow] = useState(0);
  const thresold = 10;

  function onInterval() {
    console.log("onInterval timer update"); // once per interval
    setSecondPassed((prev) => {
      const next = prev + 1;
      console.log(`next: ${next}`); // twice per interval
      setRow((prevRows) => {
        const nextRows = prevRows + 1;
        console.log(`setRow: ${nextRows}`); // 3 times per interval
        return nextRows;
      });
      return next;
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(onInterval, 1000);
    console.log(`timer setinterval: ${intervalId}`);

    return () => {
      console.log(`timer clearInterval: ${intervalId}`);
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);

  const fixedRows = useMemo(() => {
    console.log(`fixedRows: ${rows}`);
    return Array.from({ length: rows }).map((_, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="box-x" style={{ width: `${thresold}px` }}></div>
    ));
  }, [rows]);

  return (
    <>
      {fixedRows}
      <div className="box-x" style={{ width: secondsPassed % thresold }}></div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;


Even I put the code in codesandbox.io. The log still showing the set function setRow() has been called 3 times per interval. From the React documentation, there should be double invocation in strict mode. I am not sure why it has been called 3 times. Also I would like to have my code being idempotent as much as possible so the result from strict mode double invocation will not affect rendering result. Any suggestion is appreciated.
fixedRows: 0
preview-protocol.js:56 fixedRows: 0
App.jsx:30 timer setinterval: 17
App.jsx:33 timer clearInterval: 17
App.jsx:30 timer setinterval: 20
index.js:8 onInterval timer update
index.js:8 next: 1
index.js:8 setRow: 1
index.js:8 fixedRows: 1
index.js:8 fixedRows: 1
index.js:8 onInterval timer update
index.js:8 next: 2
index.js:8 setRow: 2
index.js:8 fixedRows: 2
index.js:8 next: 2
index.js:8 setRow: 2
index.js:8 setRow: 3 <- extra state update here
index.js:8 fixedRows: 3
index.js:8 onInterval timer update
index.js:8 next: 3
index.js:8 setRow: 4
index.js:8 fixedRows: 4
index.js:8 next: 3
index.js:8 setRow: 4
index.js:8 setRow: 5 <- extra state update here
index.js:8 fixedRows: 5

Environment:

Node: v22.3.0
Vite: 5.4.1
React: 18.3.1
vscode: 1.93.1
Chrome: 127.0.6533.120 arm64


Your code works as intended in this playground. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-iv6sqh?file=App.jsx,index.js.  Can you provide a reproducible example?

I am not sure why people downvote without a reason. This is what I encountered in both sandbox and my local machine. Which is valid and unexpected.

By extracting the nested set function out with the use of another useEffect(), I've managed to make the state change of rows in a more idempotent manner under double invocation in strict mode, the log now shows 2 entries per interval instead of 3, as expected.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (secondsPassed % thresold === 0)
    {
      setRow(prevRows => {
        const nextRows = prevRows + 1;
        console.log(`setRow: ${nextRows}`);
        return nextRows;
      });
    }
  }, [secondsPassed]);

App.jsx:42 timer update
App.jsx:45 next: 10
App.jsx:45 next: 10
App.jsx:54 setRow: 3
App.jsx:54 setRow: 3

The lesson I've learned is not to nest set function as the state change will not easy to determine.
Thanks the help from @WeDoTheBest4You and @Scott Z

Please see the dependency array, it now is empty. It means the code inside the hook will run only on two events - mount and unmount of the components. The code inside the hook will run on mount, and the code returned by this code will run on unmount. That is the reason the clearInterval now works only once. However this code works fine and gives you the correct results.
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect start");
    ...
  }, []);

If you still want to see how to force a clearInterval, please see below one of the ways for doing it.
Steps to do:
a) Please add a dependency to the hook.
b) The onInterval function has to move out of the hook.
And then set it as its dependency.
c) What would now happen is that on each render, the function onInterval
will be re-defined and will result a new functional object.
d) This will cause the dependency in the hook to be identified as a
change.
e) And that will lead to a re-synchronise action.
f) Every re-synchronise action will start with the execution of the
returned function and then proceed with the handler of the hook.
App.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Timer() {
  const [secondsPassed, setSecondPassed] = useState(0);
  const [rows, setRow] = useState(1);
  const thresold = 60;

  function onInterval() {
    setSecondPassed((prevSec) => {
      let currentSecond = prevSec + 1;
      console.log(currentSecond);
      if (currentSecond % thresold === 0) {
        setRow((prevRow) => prevRow + 1);
      }
      return currentSecond;
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect start');

    const intervalId = setInterval(onInterval, 1000);
    console.log(`setinterval: ${intervalId}`);

    return () => {
      console.log(`clearInterval: ${intervalId}`);
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, [onInterval]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="box-x" style={{ width: secondsPassed % thresold }}>
        seconds passed : {secondsPassed}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

Test run


I think my issue is seeing the counter of the same number has shown twice each time.

Seeing double numbers is due to react strict mode running in dev.   It is working as expected.  I you want to see how it would look in Prod, you can disable strict mode in your root react file.

As @ScottZ has commented, it is a very useful developmental aid by the React Team - loading twice, an analogy may be that it may be unwise to enter a room and close it from inside, we might be locked inside if the closure does not open due to some mistake with it. Therefore it is wise to check this way - open the room and close it from outside, then open it and enter inside and use the room for the destined purpose. This is what happens in this case as well. It helps us to see any orphaned operations we have initiated. It points out to implement clean up functions.

You can read more here : https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development

As it is in the another answer, the useEffect hook in the following code also works only on two events because of the empty dependency array. You may please check and see, the statement console.log('clearInterval') executes only on unmount - you can mock that event by page refresh)
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Clock() {
  const [now, setNow] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setNow(new Date());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      console.log('clearInterval');
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);

  return <h2>Time now is {now.getSeconds()}</h2>;
}

